# How to detect a point on which side of road in Google map

Tags: android

I am developing a app using Google map. I have draw polyline between two points on the road. And place the third marker by clicking on map. Now I want to detect the side (i.e. left or right) of the clicked point with respect to drawn route (polyline ).

Is there any Google API which provide to detect this kind of side.

Comment: Refer this answer this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43883651/7423949

Comment: But how to use Azimuth in Android. Have you used this in Android? Is any library needed for calculating Azimuth. Please suggest